# Asus TP300L touchpad stopped working after updating drivers

Tags: drivers, touchpad

Me and one of my relatives both had Asus Transformer TP300L notebooks, except I had one with Intel Core i7 and my relative had i3. My i7 had broken screen and some missing keyboard keys so I moved it's motherboard to my relative's i3. The device was entirely functional during the Windows installation and even after turning it on until I updated the drivers using Windows update. The touchpad stopped working, and I noticed some lag in the keyboard as well.
I would really like it if you could help me with that issue.